# Prevent SQL statement from updating all fields if WHERE clause is missing

Tags: mysql, sql

So just before the weekend I made a bit of a catastrophic error where I got distracted and forgot to finish my SQL-statement in the code I was working on for my site and completely left out any `WHERE`-clause before saving. This resulted in each time a new order was created, every single order in the system had it's payment-option set to whatever the new order used.

This time I was lucky I could salvage the situation with a rather recent backup and saw the error immediately (but not until after 180.000+ orders had their payment info changed) and I could manually deduct what the payments should have been for the most recent orders made after the backup had been created.

Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of a good testing environment, which I know is very bad.

**Question:** To prevent anything like this from happening again, is there any way we can set up our SQL server to prevent `UPDATE` statements to be considered `WHERE 1`, and instead be considered `WHERE 0`, where the `WHERE` clause is missing completely?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the session variable sql_safe_updates to ON with

```
SET sql_safe_updates=ON;
```

Read more about it in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates):

> For beginners, a useful startup option is --safe-updates (or
>   --i-am-a-dummy, which has the same effect). Safe-updates mode is helpful for cases when you might have issued an UPDATE or DELETE
>   statement but forgotten the WHERE clause indicating which rows to
>   modify. Normally, such statements update or delete all rows in the
>   table. With --safe-updates, you can modify rows only by specifying the
>   key values that identify them, or a LIMIT clause, or both. This helps
>   prevent accidents. Safe-updates mode also restricts SELECT statements
>   that produce (or are estimated to produce) very large result sets.
>   ... (much more info in the link provided)

Comment: I love that there is an option named `--i-am-a-dummy`. Thank you for the information, I will read up a bit on it!

Comment: It's great info, and could have been useful and most likely will be useful for some people that stumble upon this question so I did upvote it since it deserves to be seen, but unfortunately there are quite a few `UPDATE` statements in my system that uses non-key columns in `WHERE`-clauses. As Jim said in his answer, it might not be usable in production, but great for test environments which I don't have the luxury of.

Answer (score 0):

There are few IDE's like dbweaver which provides you a warning when there is on any where clause in your Update/ Delete statements. Ideally you can also use **SET sql_safe_mode=ON;
**. But this would be comfortable only in the test environment, not sure if you can enable it in production. Most right way in sql is to take a backup in an automated way using triggers before updating/ deleting